# How to find out if value1 AND value2 AND value3 are < value4?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I'm trying to wrap my head around testing multiple values in python. Let's say I have

```
value1 = 7
value2 = 2
value3 = 4
```

and I want to figure out if they're less than 10. With one value, it's obviously as simple as

```
value1 < 10
```

which results in `True`. Looking at how I'm using `and` in natural language, I would assume that testing for all is simply

```
value1 and value2 and value3 < 10
```

and it does indeed result in `True`. However, if I change `value1 = 20`, the above still stays true, while it obviously is `False`. So barring me having found a huge bug in python, I'm obviously not understanding how `and` works and unfortunately, the [only docs I can find](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) aren't helping me much (it's really hard to find anything in the docs, searching for `and`...).

```
(value1 < 10) and (value2 < 10) and (value3 < 10)
```

works as expected, but looking at it, it should be identical to my first version or

```
(value1 and value2 and value3) < 10
```

which also gives me a false `True`.

Comment: The last attemptt (`(value1 and value2 and value3) < 10`) gives you a wrong True because an integer is true if it's not zero. So, the statement within the parentheses is True. And True is smaller than 10. So, Python is correct in returning a `True`.
Use `max([value1,value2,value3])<10` to find out whether all values are smaller than 10. If the highest of them is smaller than 10, they all are.

Comment: the `and` operator takes two boolean values and combines them. So something like `(20 and 10) < 15` makes little sense. That resolve to `(True and True) < 15` which then resolves to `True < 15` which also resolves to `True`

Answer (score 2):

I'd love to answer your question.

When using an 'if' statement, you have to put 'and' between the boolean expressions, i.e. if you test for a statement like `if someVariable` and that `someVariable` has a value that's not `None` then  you'll always get a 'True' output, so instead, try this out:

```
if val1 < 10 and val2<10 and val3<10:
    <code body>
```

Allow me to explain why this does work while `if (val1 and ...) < 10` doesn't work.

This is because, the expression `val1 and val2` for example, will always yield `True`  as long as the value of both variables isn't `None`, so when you're using the expression `val1 and val2 ...` you are essentially just getting the answer as : `True < 10` which yields `True`.

I hope this answer was helpful. :D

Comment: The `if something and something:` I know and use, hence I figured I could simplify it to my first idea, since the if statement implies (to me?) that the `and` works like the and in written language.

Answer (score 1):

There are already good explanations on how the `and`operator works, so I just want to add a quick solution to testing if multiple numbers are less then another number:

```
if max(value1, value2, value3) < value4:
    print("True")
```

This works, because the built in `max`function returns the biggest number of the given values. It also works with a list or tuple as input:

```
number = [value1, value2, value3]
if max(numbers) < value4:
    print("True")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `and` operator has a bit of peculiarity which you have stumbled upon :

```
val = 5
print(1 and val)
print(2 and val)
print(0 and val)
print(-1 and val)
print(-2 and val)
```

*Output:*

```
5
5
0
5
5
```

So, **in Python `and` directly returns `0` if the first expression is evaluated to be `0` else it returns the second expression!**

So, in your case `val1 and val2 and val3` would return `val3` since the others are `non-zero`

Comment: Peculiar indeed. Is there some documentation or PEP for this available?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) you mentioned in your question, talks about this actually.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides useful built-in functions `any` and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) that allow to write readable code like this:

```
if all(v < 10 for v in (value1, value2, value3)):
    ...
```